# Delete Google Form submission based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to remove responses from Google forms that are older than a set age. I have a script to do this for the sheet, but this does not remove the responses from the form.
Removing all responses from the form is not an option as I need to retain the responses not older than the set age.
This is the script which works on  the sheet, which I need an equivalent for on the form.

[script working on sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZoDu.png)

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //give your sheet name below instead of Sheet1
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();


  var currentDate = new Date();
  var oneweekago = new Date();
  oneweekago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1095);
    
  for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
    var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    
    if(tempdate < oneweekago)
    {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

I've created a `Form` and I managed to delete the submits older than a week. There are a few methods that you have to use to achieve that goal:

### Steps

- Open your `Form`. You can use [getActiveForm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getActiveForm()) if you are using an Apps Script project contained in a `Form` document. Otherwise, use [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openById(String)) or [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openByUrl(String))
- Get all the responses with [getResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses)
- Get the `timestamp` of each with [getTimestamp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#gettimestamp)
- Compare the two timestamps with a simple if statement
- When the condition is true

  - Get the id of the response with [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getid)
  - Delete the response with [deleteResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteresponseresponseid)

### Code

```js
function deleteSubmissions(){

  var oneweekago = new Date();
  oneweekago.setDate(oneweekago.getDate() - 1095);

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm() // FormApp.openById() | FormApp.openByUrl()
  var responses = form.getResponses()

  for (var i=0; i<responses.length; i++){
    var r = responses[i]
    var responseTime = r.getTimestamp()
    if (responseTime > oneweekago){
      var id = r.getId()
      form.deleteResponse(id)
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

- [FormApp: getActiveForm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getActiveForm())
- [FormApp: openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openById(String))
- [FormApp: openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openByUrl(String))
- [Form: getResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses)
- [Response: getTimestamp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#gettimestamp)
- [Response: getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getid)
- [Form: deleteResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteresponseresponseid)

Comment: You're a star, thanks a lot. Just tested on a form and it removed the submissions.

Comment: I can't work out how you arrived at 1095 to represent one week?. I always assume time periods in apps script are measured in milliseconds. I'll be testing this out with some dummy data to make sure it works as expected, so I'll figure this out in testing - but it's awkward since timestamps in forms can't be manually edited.

Comment: My daft mistake. You've quite rightly reacted to the spreadsheet code I posted. Subsequent failed attempts on forms (not shown) were using a different method as I was advised to use time rather than dates. BTW thanks again for your solution, it's just what I needed.

Comment: FWIW, you can use regular millisecond math. Just make sure you're comparing `new Date(oneWeekAgo)` to `new Date(r.getTimestamp())`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script to delete the response from the Form same as you write for the spreadsheet.[Please refer this link for deleting form single response by Id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteresponseresponseid)

Comment: This is my current attempt. Again, works to remove submissions from the sheet, but does not work for the form https://prnt.sc/10pxhlx